# Is it ok to output `\xA0` or `\xC2A0` in my HTML pages, or do I need to escape it as `&nbsp;`?

Tags: javascript, html, encoding

I have a large JS codebase, not all of which I can control, where we use non-breaking spaces in locale files, for what non-breaking spaces are actually meant to be used (to prevent wrapping).

Currently, these non-breaking spaces are specified in `.yml` files as `\_`, which our YAML loader is replacing with `\xA0` (the actual byte 160, not the escape sequence, which is ASCII for nbsp), and that `\xA0` is getting output directly to the browser.

As far as I can see, these do work. They're not getting wrapped. But given the existence of `&nbsp;`, it feels "wrong" to output the ASCII directly.

I've been googling for quite a while, but I can't find any information on this...

Is it ok to output `\xA0` (the actual byte 160, not the escape sequence) as part of my HTML? Or should I always encode as `&nbsp;`? (and if the latter, why? What's the downside?)

Comment: `\xA0` is not ASCII, it's an escape sequence that can be used in JS strings.

Comment: You would only use `&nbsp;` if you were writing HTML strings. But you aren't, you're working on the DOM, right?

Comment: @bergi, yes, I mean it's outputting the actual character 160. I just have no better way of expressing that, since it's indistinguishable from a normal space. As for HTML string vs the DOM, not entirely sure what you mean.

Comment: Are you writing clientside js code that interacts with the browser DOM, or do you write js code that emits HTML?

Comment: HTML uses Unicode codepoints encoded with a document encoding, allowing named and numeric character entity references.  You're asking if you should avoid encoding [U+00A0](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm) and instead use the named character entity reference? JavaScript and YAML is just background info?

Comment: @TomBlodget yes, I'm asking exactly that. Can I just output U+00A0? Or do I need to escape it?. I guess JS and YAML is only background info, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3):

Printing no-break spaces in HTML as `\xA0` escape sequences via JavaScript strings is in fact printing the actual no-break space characters themselves.

Since no-break spaces don't have any special meaning in HTML, it makes no meaningful difference whether you print the characters directly or use the character references. (User agents that can't handle UTF-8 encoded HTML may beg to differ, but I suspect those are a theoretical problem.)

Comment: Servers that miss to annotate UTF8-encoded HTML with the appropriate `content-type` *are* a (practical) problem, though.

Comment: @Bergi: That's true, especially if the server config is not within the author's control.

Comment: To clarify, the escape sequence is not being used. That's just the only way I have to describe what character is going out. What's being output is the actual binary character 160. As in, the same as the output of this: String.fromCharCode(160)

Comment: @Daniel Magliola: In which case you're outputting the character itself, which is even simpler :D That said, my second paragraph applies exactly as it did before.